# Linux x86_64 asm, hello world prints nothing

Tags: assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

I have written x86_64 assembly before, but not on Linux using gas and I can't seem to get this simple hello world example to work (creating a reference by assembling a C program with gcc produces a lot of asm code that does not seem too relevant for this minimal example). The program runs fine but nothing is written to stdout.

```
.section .rodata
    message: .string "hello, world!\n"

.section .text
    .globl main
    .type main, @function
main:
    mov $1, %rax
    mov $1, %rdi
    mov message, %rsi
    mov $14, %rdx
    syscall
    mov $60, %rax
    mov $0, %rdi
    syscall
```

Calling conventions seem to be fine, gbd tells me that the first `syscall` returns `-14`. Even after reading the write manpage I'm not sure what that means, is the write system call run at all?

Comment: Try `mov $message, %rsi` instead.  `mov message, %rsi` moves the first 8 bytes of `message` into `rsi` whereas `mov $message, %rsi` moves the address of `message` into `rsi`.

Comment: Yes, that's it. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @fuz: use `lea message(%rip), %rsi` for 64-bit static addresses.  `mov $message, %rsi` is never the best choice for a PIE or non-PIE executable, regardless of whether it picks a 64-bit immediate or 32-bit sign-extended.

Comment: @PeterCordes I know.  I wanted a minimal-invasive change to clarify the underlying misunderstanding of how to specify immediate operands in AT&T syntax.